# Java OpenCV Bindings

Tags: java, opencv

I am looking for OpenCV java bindings, all the references point to the processing library. I know processing is java but isn't there a standalone java lib? or should just use processing libs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have just found this, a java wrapper of OpenCV :
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Not tested, but I would love to have your point of view about this.

Answer (score 11):

JavaCV is Java wrapper of OpenCV : https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv
Here is good tutorial on [eclipse project configuration for JavaCV](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2017/01/javacv-configuration-in-windows.html)

And [few applications using JavaCV](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/search/label/OpenCV-JavaCV) is also posted there.

Answer (score 7):

OpenCV now has an official Desktop Java port. It is still a work-in-progress and you have to compile opencv, but you should definitely take a look as it will be much friendly than JavaCV.

Take a look at these links for information:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/2137/wrapping-opencv-with-desktop-java-building-for-64/

And this:

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/fe0d07ae53ba9e6dcd1e470165ed0a85cbfce006

**UPDATE (Fev 2013):**

Java bindings [have been released.](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html)

Comment: A word of caution for people who want to use the Java bindings; the Java bindings only seem to cover a portion of what is available in the C++ version. Make sure you check that whatever you need is available before you start in order to avoid unpleasant surprises!

Answer (score 4):

javacv looks pretty good, works with my webcam and images in a custom format. I'm just still looking for a possibility to performant create an IplImage from an array of floats.

Answer (score 3):

I found this forum post where people are attempting pretty much the same thing:
http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/3531/#44302