# Simple shape recognition of a set of points in Java

Tags: java, geometry, pattern-recognition

I have a set of randomly distributed point in a coordinate system and I'm interested in recognising if some of the points form any geometric figures like a square, circle, parallelogram or simple lines.

Do exists any libaries or algorithms for recognising patterns?
Or maybe some tipps how to program something like that?

Answer (score 3):

[Haar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features) and [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) are the standard algorithms.

A good library for image recognition - admittedly more for faces and vehicles and such, rather than geometry but that's just a question of training - is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which has [Java bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037579/java-opencv-bindings) if you dig enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a complex issue. One of the many tools you might want to read about is the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), it's used mainly to detect lines but can be adapted to other shapes.