# Any existing java or matlab library to count how many person in a room using a IP camera?

Tags: java, matlab, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

Any existing java or matlab library to

- do image subtracting with background
  image
- clear out the shade
- do dilate and erode to count out how
  many person in a room?

Comment: Your question seems very vague for a very complex subject.

Comment: @Samuel, seems, but computer vision is quite evolved and what he asks for is already done in industry at large.

Comment: @Rekin His question was not as concise as it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV will help you do what you want, and there are Java bindings for it: [Java OpenCV Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037579/java-opencv-bindings)

In MATLAB you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/).

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has just the toolbox for this purpose. I'd highly recommend viewing [Matlab's video processing webinar](http://www.mathworks.com/company/events/webinars/wbnr43152.html?id=43152&p1=688660656&p2=688660674). There are examples of object counting:

- how many cars drove by camera placed on a highway,
- image segmentation for measuring rice grain quality.

It might be a perfect fit for you.