# how to detect shapes in an image?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-recognition

I want to detect a circle, rectangle shaped object in an image and read the information from that object. Is there any api in java which will be helpful to me?

Ex: Detect a round shaped coin in a white background and obtain information about that that coin like ( value of a coin, etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: This is something i did in my artificial intelligence course. We did something similar like detecting the #7 in an image, distinguishing faces, etc. but we used Python. Or maybe use the Canny Edge Detection algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785419/detection-of-coins-and-fit-ellipses-on-an-image/4788874#4788874) to a similar question for C++.

For Java, you can use the [OpenCV wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037579/java-opencv-bindings).  However, once you understand the essence of the approach you should be able to solve your problem using whichever framework is available.

Answer (score 2):

Circles are perfect targets for the Hough transform. Check this out [Detect circles with HT and OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20190405152844/http://www.andol.info:80/hci/749.htm)

Rectangles are a bit harder since the Hough Transform is not rotation invariant. You can go into edge detection and fast fitting ([Fast line and rectangle detection by clustering and grouping](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k03727633k053u68/))