# What is algorithm to detect a shape on some image?

Tags: java, algorithm, detection

So far I've found topics which describe how to compare to images by its preferences (saturation, blur,...) to see if they are identical.

However, what algorithm can help me to detect is an image (taken by a photo camera, mobile camera, etc.) contains a circle for example or a square?

In the database, I will have a list of objects (circle, square, polygons,...) and the algorithm should compare if any of these objects is present on a photo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522771/how-to-detect-shapes-in-an-image

Comment: You can use JavaCV for detecting shapes in images. IF you are interested in the algorithms you can go through OpenCV source code and wiki

Comment: @VusP what about polygon detection?

Comment: search hough transfrom

Comment: switch to frequency domain via DFFT/DFT or DFCT/DCT and check the frequency distribution. if it is 'analog' like (smooth) then its most likely a photo (real world image) if it is pulse-like then it is drawed imaged (vector,cartoon,render,...) specific patterns can detect presence of basic shapes like rectangle,line,circle... this with combination of filters and image area selection and segmentation leads to more advanced computer vision algorithms ...

Comment: Try [Viola Jones Object Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework)