# Using Webcam in Java Under Linux

Tags: linux, image-processing, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, webcam

I am working on an Image Processing project using JavaEE Eclipse under Linux Ubuntu 11.4,
 and of course i am using a Webcam

Ubuntu can see the Webcam through any webcam program (ex: cheese)
but when using it in coding through Java Eclipse it can't determine the device name of the webcam!

I have tried the webcam of the laptop, and another webcam

Answer (score 1):

[Java OpenCV Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037579/java-opencv-bindings) talks about using the OpenCV library. I've not used the Java version, but the Python bindings are pretty amazing.