# Is there any OSS library or paper that does Vector path tracing of mono bitmaps?

Tags: java, vector-graphics, vectorization

i am just interested in how these things work and am after a library or paper that describes the approach that most of these take. At a guess they probably support a few basic constructs.

- line
- arc
- dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A large part of image processing is about reasoning about an image at a higher level of abstraction than just pixels, which is exactly what you need to do to [vectorise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_to_vector) an image.

As such, [OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) is well worth looking at. It contains various image processing functions for blob detection and there appear to be [Java OpenCV Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2037579/42473) these days.

If this doesn't suit and nor do any of the other libraries listed in [What is the best java image processing library/approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603283/42473), then your easiest option might be to write a java wrapper library around [autotrace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autotrace/) or other non java vectorisation library.