# Convert a raster image to a vector one in Java (e.g. jpg -> svg)

Tags: java, api, vector, raster

I would like to know how to convert a raster image into a vector one (e.g. jpg -> svg) in java. Does anyone has any idea about a sample code or api or library to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716888/raster-to-vector-shape

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any OSS library or paper that does Vector path tracing of mono bitmaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480079/is-there-any-oss-library-or-paper-that-does-vector-path-tracing-of-mono-bitmaps)

Comment: i need more help please