# check sign detection in image processing?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, edge-detection

I want to detect position of check mark on paper return relative position in X,Y coordinates.

Is there anyway to start this in java coding?

Comment: Not really a question for Stack Overflow. Check out [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/) and [JavaCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037579/java-opencv-bindings)

Comment: @ User : your Question is of very low quality.

Answer (score 1):

- Take picture of page;
- Rotate and scale it to normalize its layout; using a QR code or similar markings can help with this step;
- adjust it to 1-bit color;
- look at the rectangles into which your check marks might appear;

  - determine what %age of "black" vs. "white" is considered a "valid mark"

For finer-grained controls, you could go full monty with a genetic algorithm training system, or similar, but I actually expect that step 2 (rotate and scale to normalize) will be the most difficult step, unless you have high-quality scans.